# Varchar type not acting as it should in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm making an academic application with dummy data. In my database, I have several tables, including a restaurant table and an expenses table (which is temporary).
When inserting the data of a restaurant into the expenses table to denormalize it (because it comes from .csv files), something curious happens to me.
It turns out that depending on the size of the restaurant name they are inserted correctly or not (knowing that it is a VARCHAR longer than the longest element). While doing tests I have realized that the difference in sizes between the different restaurant names makes it look out of place. When a short name comes and a long one, it's like the short one has to take up a lot of spaces and it gets out of place.
The structure of the two tables is as follows (names are in spanish):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS restaurante(
   id_restaurante INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   nombre VARCHAR(30),
   direccion VARCHAR(40),
   productividad_media INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gastos_temp(
   id_gasto INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   tipo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   fecha DATE NOT NULL,
   precio_bruto INT NOT NULL,
   precio_neto INT NOT NULL,
   restaurante VARCHAR(18)
);
```

Here I show you an example of operation

[image: Example]

It is true that the same thing happened to me when inserting the data into the restaurant table, however I played a little with the name size and it worked. It's strange because with the same size it doesn't work either.

I've tried playing with the table size but it didn't work. I've also checked the embed and the .csv, but both are fine though. I've checked the MySQL manual to see if VARCHARs had any properties that I don't know about, but I haven't found anything either.
I'm sure it's a small detail I'm leaving out.

Comment: Your file has `CRLF` line breaks. The output you're seeing comes from line wrapping due to the CR characters.

Comment: If you're loading with `LOAD DATA INFILE`, use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`

Comment: Don't arbitrarily limit the size of text fields. You're not saving any space. 20 characters takes as much space in `varchar(20)` as `varchar(255)`.

Comment: How are you loading the data into gastos_temp?

Comment: With '\r\n' it worked Barman, thank you very much